# PHP require a file and get error in WAMPServer

Tags: php

I require a db_connect file to my model. I use the db_connect in other projects too, but in this case I got an error.

My folder structure:

```
blog 
  - css (dir)
  - js (dir)
  - model (dir)
    - model.php
  - tools (dir)
    - db_connect.php
  - index.php
```

In the model I require the file:

```
require("../tools/db_connect.php");
```

I got these errors, and I cant solve it.

[image]

When I used the dwoo template engine I got the some problem.

I am using WAMPserver and PHPStorm on Windows 7.

Comment: Those error messages are pretty straightforward aren't they? So please check your include paths and if that didn't help provide us all the relecant code. (hint: don't use absolute paths, try use `__DIR__` instead)

Comment: Yes, straightforward. But, I said use these solution in other projects where I havent got the error. I searching for the problem in whole day.

Comment: did you try using `__DIR__`? also I see you're using normal slashes `/` instead of backslashes `\ `; remember that you're working under windows. Also enquote your path in single quotes instead of double, that is, you won't insert `\t` by accident.

Comment: I take it the same folder with the model.php and the require is good now. This is a good solution provisionally.
I try it now.

Comment: I remember I had the same problem under Windows and it had been solved by changing slashes to backslashes.

Comment: Yes it is good. Thanx.

Comment: Did my solution work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do `include`, the error you are getting is because it can not locate that file

that means that where you were you think your file is located your file is not there

- check your file location from where you php file is stored go though folder by folder

Comment: The PHPStorm help me localize the file, and the PHPStorm offer me it.

Comment: I take it the same folder with the model.php and the require is good now. This is a good solution provisionally.

Comment: yes @PumpkinSeed that means that where you were locating your file was not correct